# Combine ng-admin and ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-admin

I have `AngularJS`(1.4.9) project that is build with usage of `ui-router` and have few states like this:

```
.state('overview', {
  url: '/overview',
  parent: 'dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/overview.html'
})
.state('settings', {
  url: '/settings',
  parent: 'dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'settings/views/index.html',
  controller: "SettingsCtrl"
})
```

Now I want to add want to integrate `ng-admin`(0.9.1) to it. I have tested it as standalone app with standalone html as described in [docs](http://docshttps://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin/blob/v0.9.1/doc/Getting-started.md) and it works. But I couldn't find a way to add it to current project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My 'just works' solution is to add to main project states external link of `ng-admin`:

```
  .state('database', {
      onEnter: function($window) {
          $window.open('/ng-admin/ng-admin.html', '_self');
      }
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to change your app parent state with ng-admin like below

```
// from
myApp.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('send-post', {
        parent: 'main',
        url: '/sendPost/:id',
        params: { id: null },
        controller: sendPostController,
        controllerAs: 'controller',
        template: sendPostControllerTemplate
    });
});

// to
myApp.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('send-post', {
        parent: 'ng-admin', // <= this has changed
        url: '/sendPost/:id',
        params: { id: null },
        controller: sendPostController,
        controllerAs: 'controller',
        template: sendPostControllerTemplate
    });
});
```

For reference please check updated document [ng-admin](https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin/blob/master/UPGRADE-1.0.md)